# Which data type should be chosen for big values in Java?

Tags: java, variables, int, double

What data type can handle the biggest values in Java?

I have to store big numbers (I don't know the actual size yet) without commas.

In C, I think that I would use something like an unsigned long int.

What is the best type to use in Java for that?

Comment: you read the doc of `BigInteger`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data type that can hold the highest value in Java is [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). If you don't know what your maximum value is I would suggest using that.

Answer (score 6):

The largest primitive type in java is `long`, which is a signed 64-bit integer - max value `9223372036854775807`

For arbitrarily large integers, use an instance of `Biginteger`.

Comment: It should be "The largest primitive integer type...". double is primitive and can contain far larger numbers.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan depends how you define "largest". If it's "number of digits", then `long` is the "largest", because it holds (ie prints) more digits than `double`.

Comment: By number of digits stored, long and double are the same size, since they are both 64 bit binary types. Number of digits printed is very arbitrary, because Double's toString rounds to avoid printing the hundreds of digits that would be needed to exactly represent some double values.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Actually no. Unlike `long`, not all of the 64 bits of a `double` are used to represent the digits: There's 1 sign bit and 11 exponent digits, leaving just 52 bits for the significand (the numbers). You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary64). This means that the largest whole number that is accurately representable by `double` is `4503599627370496`, which is 3 digits smaller/shorter than `long`'s largest value.